# Import Error : Not able to use keras_applications on Mac M1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Code**

```
from keras_applications import imagenet_utils as utils
from keras_applications import correct_pad
```

**Error**

---

[image]

```
import keras
from keras_applications import vgg16
```

Or, preferably, this equivalent formulation:

```
from keras import applications
```

---

**Approaches Used**

I have already imported `keras` at the top and am also using `tensorflow-macos` version for Mac M1.

---

I have also tried to manually set the `_KERAS_BACKEND = 'tensorflow'` in the `__init__.py` of the keras_applications library in the lib folder but this is not working for some reason.

Comment: Which Tensorflow version have you installed? However you can fix this error using `!pip install keras_applications` and execute the code again.

Comment: No it wasn't working using pip install